# How to load a function after an onclick event

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="webpage.css">
    <style type="text/css">
        #myCanvas {left: 500px; top:500px;
        border: 2px solid black;}
    </style>
    <title>Canvas Basics</title>
</head>
<body>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="750" height="250">

</canvas>
<br>
<span id="count">3</span>seconds
<button id="next">Play</button>

</body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var can;
    var ctx;
    var finish=false;
    function ranNum(max)
    {
        return Math.ceil(Math.random()*max)+1;
    }
window.onclick= function() {
    (function () {
        var counter = 3;
        setInterval(function () {
            counter--;
            if (counter >= 0) {
                span = document.getElementById("count");
                span.innerHTML = counter;
            }
            if (counter === 0) {
                alert('sorry, out of time');
                clearInterval(counter);
            }
        }, 1000);
    })();
}
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var nextBtn = document.getElementById('next');
        nextBtn.addEventListener('click',next,false);

        can = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
        ctx = can.getContext('2d');
        x1 = 0;
        x2 = 0;
        x3 = 0;
        x4 = 0;

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(can.width-100, 0);
        ctx.lineTo(can.width-100, 400);
        ctx.stroke();


        ctx.fillStyle="red";
        ctx.fillRect(x1,50,50,25);

        ctx.fillStyle="blue";
        ctx.fillRect(x2,100,50,25);

        ctx.fillStyle="orange";
        ctx.fillRect(x3,150,50,25);

        ctx.fillStyle="green";
        ctx.fillRect(x4,200,50,25);

        function next()
        {
            var a = ranNum(10);
            var b = ranNum(10);
            var c = ranNum(10);
            var d = ranNum(8);

            if (x1 <200) {
                ctx.clearRect (0,0, can.width, can.height);
            }
            else {
                ctx.clearRect (120,0, can.width, can.height);
            }

            //ctx.clearRect (0,0, can.width, can.height);
            x1+= a;
            x2+=b;
            x3+=c;
            x4+=d;
            ctx.fillStyle="red";
            ctx.fillRect(x1,50,50,25);

            ctx.fillStyle="blue";
            ctx.fillRect(x2,100,50,25);

            ctx.fillStyle="orange";
            ctx.fillRect(x3,150,50,25);

            ctx.fillStyle="green";
            ctx.fillRect(x4,200,50,25);

            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(can.width-100, 0);
            ctx.lineTo(can.width-100, 400);
            ctx.stroke();

            //context.font="16px Ariel";
            //context.fillStyle="black";

            if (finish == false) {
                if (x1 > 625) {
                    //ctx.fillText("Red Winner",10,80);
                    winner(x1);
                }
                else if (x2 > 625) {
                    //ctx.fillText("Blue Winner",10,80);
                    winner(x2);
                }
                else if (x3 > 625) {
                    //ctx.fillText("Orange Winner",10,80);
                    winner(x3);
                }
                else if (x4 > 625) {
                    //ctx.fillText("Green Winner",10,80);
                    winner(x4);
                }
                //tTimeout(next, 40);
            }

            setTimeout(next, 40);
        }

        function winner(temp)
        {
            ctx.fillStyle= "black";

            finish=true;
            ctx.font="30px Arial";

            ctx.fillText("Winner!", 10,80);
            //alert(x1,x2,x3,x4);
            switch(temp)
            {
                case x1:
                    ctx.fillStyle="red";
                    ctx.fillText("Red", 10,150);
                    break;
                case x2:
                    ctx.fillStyle="blue";
                    ctx.fillText("Blue", 10,150);
                    break;
                case x3:
                    ctx.fillStyle="orange";
                    ctx.fillText("Orange", 10,150);
                    break;
                case x4:
                    ctx.fillStyle="green";
                    ctx.fillText("Green", 10,150);
                    break;
                default:
                    alert("");

            }
        }


    });
</script>
```

I have a code that creates a grid of numbers. If you click on the number it changes to green, click on it again turns to red. I need to know how to create a button that changes all to green and another that changes all to red..... the part before this does not count just trying to get the race to start after the button is clicked and the count down reaches 0?

Comment: Can you post additional information, such as sample html and the changeColor function?

Comment: i dont know how to do that ive been trying and it just keeps say i need to add text inbetween

Comment: any idea? time is important any input would help

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

1. Use `black` class to start with and assign `red` and `green` classes on button presses

   ```
   $(".myDiv").on("click", function() {
       if ($(this).hasClass("black")) {
           $(this).addClass("green");
       } else if ($(this).hasClass("green")) {
           $(this).addClass("red");
       } else if ($(this).hasClass("red")) {
           $(this).addClass("black");
       }
   ```
2. Color using css
3. Change all buttons using the class

   ```
   $(".green").removeClass("green").addClass("red");
   ```

Comment: now i just need to add two buttons that when pressed turns all the days on the calendar green or if the second one is clicked turns them all red

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to each "calendar day" element. For example:

```
<div class="myDiv">1</div>
```

But instead of "myDiv", I would recommend a more descriptive class name.

```
<div class="day-on-calendar">1</div>
```

Then, to select all the elements with that class:

```
$(".day-on-calendar")
```

And to change the color of all of them:

```
$(".day-on-calendar").css("color", "green");
```

To change the color when you click a certain element:

```
<button id="all-green-button">Turn all the dates green</button>

$("#all-green-button").click(function(){
    $(".day-on-calendar").css("color", "green");
});
```

Comment: i dont know where to put that in my code also the days in month dont have set divs i would have to change the whole code

Comment: Put the HTML code wherever you want it to show up on the page. Put the jQuery code anywhere within the document.ready function.

Comment: You shouldn't have to change the HTML very much. Just make sure each button has a unique ID (like "all-red-button" or "all-green-button") and each day on the calendar has a certain class ("myDiv" works for this, but you can use any class you want).